# Is there a continuous function $f:S\rightarrow S$ such that $f(x)\ne x$ for all $x\in S$ where $S=[-3,-2]\cup [2,3]$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is there a continuous function $f:S\rightarrow S$ such that $f(x)\ne x$ for all $x\in S$ where $S=[-3,-2]\cup [2,3]$?

This question arose because I was solving [this](http://www.isical.ac.in/~admission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/MMA-2017.pdf) which says that only one answer out of four is correct, so in Q4, I know that for (A), the given statement is false.

Comment: Try to solve it graphically.

Comment: So I should have $S\times S$ in my mind when looking at these functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, take the function $f(x)=-x$.